# Distributing values according to a given continuous probability distribution

Tags: distributions, probability, algorithms

I have a series of continuous probability distributions and the intervals for each distribution of possible values.  Now I want to use the distributions to distribute values of a random variable among agents.  I have thought of one way to do this, and I'm curious if this is an acceptable method.  This is how I would do it:

```
Let P(A<X<B) be a given pdf, where A,B are min and max values for random 
variable X.
Divide the spread between A and B into an arbitrarily large amount of 'chunks' 
or ranges.
For each chunk, represented as a range, say between a and b, make a table 
where P(a<X<b) relates to the range a,b.
For each agent receiving a value of random variable X, use a random number 
generator, look up the result in the table, give the agent a value in the 
range (a,b).
```

Assuming that this is an acceptable technique, I'm still curious as to what an acceptable amount of granularity for the 'chunks' would be.  I hope this wan't too confusing and any feedback would be much appreciated.

edit: All of my functions take the form of f(x) = a/(b*x)+c over some interval.  They are all easily integrable.

Comment: It rather depends on the smoothness of your pdf as you are going to interpolate.  But if you can calculate $\Pr (a<X<b)$ then presumably you have some way of integrating the pdf, which rather changes possible approaches to the question.  Perhaps you could tell us what form the pdf takes.

Comment: If you can easily integrate the pdf, to acquire the cdf, can you easily invert the CDF, $F^{-1}$? If so, just plug uniform random numbers into $F^{-1}$ and the resulting numbers will be a draw from your distribution

Comment: @Macro  can you elaborate on this, please?  If I understand you correctly, this would be using the cdf where P(X<B) for some value B, the lower bound always being A.  Then I would solve for B, and have the invers function?

Comment: Let $F(x) = P(X \leq x)$. Then set $y = F(x)$ and solve for $x$. The general solution to that inversion problem is the inverse CDF, $F^{-1}$. If you generate Uniform(0,1) random numbers and plug them into $F^{-1}$ you have random numbers with CDF $F$. For example, $F(x) = 1 - e^{-x}$ for $x > 0$ is the exponential CDF. The general solution to $y = 1 - e^{-x}$ in terms of $x$ is $x = F^{-1}(y) = -\log(1-y)$. Then, it follows that if $u$ is a uniform(0,1) random variable, then $-\log(1-u)$ has an exponential distribution.

Comment: @Macro - I think that is an answer rather than a comment, and was what I was hinting at.  My only slight extension is that even if you do not have a closed form for $F^{-1}$, you may be able to find a reasonable approximation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your problem it sounds like the CDF will have a simple closed form that is easily inverted. In that case I'd suggest what is called the "inversion method" for generating from the distribution:

Let $F(x)=P(X≤x)$. Then set $y=F(x)$ and solve for $x$. The general solution to that inversion problem is the inverse CDF, $F^{-1}$. If you generate Uniform(0,1) random numbers and plug them into $F^{-1}$ you have random numbers with CDF $F$.

For example, $F(x)=1−e^{-x}$ for $x>0$ is the exponential CDF. The general solution to $y=1−e^{−x}$ in terms of $x$ is

$$ x=F^{-1}(y)=−\log(1−y).$$ 
Then, it follows that if $u$ is a ${\rm Uniform}(0,1)$ random variable, then $-\log(1−u)$ has an exponential distribution.

**Edit:** From your problem statement, the density is proportional to $f(x) = \frac{a}{bx} + c$ on some interval $(A,B)$. Therefore, the CDF is

$$ F(x) = \frac{1}{k} \int_{A}^{x} \frac{a}{by} + c \ dy = \frac{1}{k} \cdot \left( \frac{a}{b} \cdot \log(x/A) + c(x - A) \right) $$

where $k$ is the *normalizing constant*, which is calculated [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13307/how-to-turn-a-function-into-a-probability-density/13308#13308). This closed form of the inverse of this CDF involves the [Lambert W Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html) (thanks, @whuber), so I'm going to be lazy and solve for it numerically. Here is a very crude method of doing that in `R` using [bisection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method), implemented as the `uniroot` function:

```
# Find the point at which the CDF above equals p, for parameters values
# a,b,c and predefined domain (A,B)
F_inv = function(p,a,b,c,A,B)
{
   k = (a * log(B/A))/b + c(B-A)
   br = c(A,B)
   G = function(x) (a * log(x/A)/b + c(x-A))/k - p
   return( uniroot(G,br)$root ) 
}

# x is a sample from this distribution with a=2, b=5, c=.8, A=10, B=20. 
x = rep(0,1000)
for(i in 1:1000) x[i] = F_inv(runif(1),2,5,.8,10,20)
```

Comment: +1 This CDF has a "closed form inverse" using the "ProductLog" ([Lambert W function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html)).  Wolfram Alpha will [compute it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ProductLog[1]) and lists some of its properties.

Comment: Thanks @whuber, I didn't know that. I wrote it down and stared at it for a minute and it looked unsolvable. But, it seems like there's a special function for many such problems.

Comment: There are `R` implementations of W: here's one promising package (I haven't checked it out) at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/LambertW/index.html and another is blogged at http://www.r-bloggers.com/lambert%E2%80%99s-w-function-and-the-generalised-logarithm/.